# Cloudflare is breaking my recaptcha by replacing javascript with rocketscript

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha, cloudflare

I run my website through cloudflare and which has [Rocket Loader](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168056-What-does-Rocket-Loader-do-) Enabled. Rocket loader appears to replace javascript with "rocketscript". This occasionally breaks my recaptcha v2 from loading with the following errors in the chrome console:

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2//styles__ltr.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
GET https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2//recaptcha__en.js net::ERR_ABORTED
Refused to execute script from 'https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2//recaptcha__en.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
Uncaught ReferenceError: recaptcha is not defined
Refused to apply style from 'https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2//styles__ltr.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
GET https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2//recaptcha__en.js net::ERR_ABORTED
Refused to execute script from 'https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2//recaptcha__en.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
Uncaught ReferenceError: recaptcha is not defined
```

When I look at the source code it has the following "rocketscript"

```
<div>
   <script type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketoptimized="true">var onloadCallback = function() {grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {'sitekey' : 'blahblah-QBB', 'theme' : 'light' });};</script>
   <div id="recaptcha">
      <div>
         <div style="width: 302px; height: 422px; position: relative;">
            <div style="width: 302px; height: 422px; position: absolute;">
               <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/fallback?k=blahblah&amp;hl=en&amp;v=vxxxxxxx&amp;t=xxxxx" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width: 302px; height: 422px; border-style: none;">
               </iframe>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div style="border-style: none; bottom: 12px; left: 25px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; right: 25px; background: #f9f9f9; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; border-radius: 3px; height: 60px; width: 300px;">
            <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; ">
            </textarea>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <script async="" defer="" data-rocketsrc="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&amp;render=explicit" type="text/rocketscript" data-rocketoptimized="true"></script>
</div>
```

Why is rocket loader breaking my javascript only sometimes?

Comment: Can you have rocket loader ignore your captcha script? https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169436-How-can-I-have-Rocket-Loader-ignore-my-script-s-in-Automatic-Mode-

Comment: Yes but I want to know why its breaking it sometimes and not always.